# What does it mean by implementing a DOM

Tags: java, javascript, c++, dom

I came across this phrase "implementing a DOM" and want to ask what does that mean exactly?

I think DOM is implemented by C++ in most browser. and DOM API is exposed to users through Javascript? So what does it mean to implement the DOM using PHP/Java or even Javascript such as jsdom did.

A more specific question is why would people want to re-implement DOM using other languages?

Thanks

Comment: Please add more context, maybe the whole paragraph where you read this in?

Comment: I've no idea what you're asking or how it's related to the Java programming language.

Comment: There's a DOM implementation for Java... :)

Comment: @inflag: sure, there's likely a DOM implementation for [brainf**k](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck), but that still doesn't tell how it relates to the question.

Comment: @Hovercraft: I'd like to see the source of that one :) To the point though: The OT is probably not aware that there is a DOM implementation for most languages out there, which might actually be part of his question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think DOM is implemented by C++ in most browser. and DOM API is exposed to users through Javascript?

Maybe.  I'm sure that Internet Explorer uses [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28VS.85%29.aspx) for manipulating the DOM.  As it's a set of [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) components, it is available for use in many different languages.  It's likely that this implementation is written in C++, but it doesn't really matter from the application's point of view.

> So what does it mean to implement the DOM using PHP/Java or even Javascript such as jsdom did.

[DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) is the recommended application programming interface for working with XML documents.  Implementing a DOM basically means implementing an XML parser and tree structure library that complies to this interface.

This is API is a convention.  It allows people familiar with DOM manipulation to "feel at home" when they use a new library.  This usually happens when you use another language (e.g. server-side Java, Python, Ruby and client-side JavaScript), but may happen if you start using another project in the same language, but that project uses a different library.

> A more specific question is why would people want to re-implement DOM using other languages?

Because not everyone agrees on which programming language to use.  If you really like [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell) and you choose to manipulate documents in XML format (i.e. persisting data, or for communication with other software that understands XML -- web scaping, for instance), then you'll need to manipulate XML documents in Haskell.  Then, you'll need a library for XML in Haskell.

Note that, even if people agreed on a single programming language, there would probably still be many different libraries as people disagree on political grounds, such as software licensing issues and programming style, desired features, etc.